# Using ks.test to check generated random values with an empirical cumulative distribution function

Tags: statistics, monte-carlo, simulation

I was given a task to generate pseudo-random numbers from the seed that could fit to the given distribution function (and use with ks.test to test it.) However, my code seems to be faulty. I followed the steps we used in our  practice questions (only found empirical cumulative function, that was mentioned in our lecture, was found from internet.) I’m quite a beginner in R and I do not know how to fix the code. I appreciate your help and tips.

```
set.seed(seed)
n<-10000
u<- runif(10000)

F <- function(x){
  return(((x + 9)^2) / ((6 + 9 + 1)^2)*(x >= -9)*(x<7)+
           1*(x >= 7))
}

# empirical
ecdf <- ecdf(u)
ks_test <- ks.test(ecdf, F)
#Error in x[!is.na(x)] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'
```

Comment: What is F in this case? and what is `ecdf`?

Comment: ecdf is the Empirical distribution function and and F is the given distribution function what to which the generated numbers must be suitable for.

Comment: I am confused why you have `ecdf(u)` if you are trying to generate samples from the empirical distribution, you should use the INVERSE cdf, not the cdf

Comment: (a) this is not the site to ask programming questions (b)  `ks.test` takes a vector of numbers not a distribution as its first argument, (c) you have $u$ taking values uniformly between $0$ and $1$ but $F$ having support on $[-9,7]$ so with so large a sample you might hope any plausible test would say they have different distributions, and (d) I do not understand what you are trying to do.